# How to know the Android device id in the building process of Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have been developing an Android home app using Android Studio.
The app is kind of special app, I need to modify the android device with adb shell commands before installing the apk file.
In order to archive this, I wrote a gradle task in build.gradle file, then execute a bash script file.
This approach is fine except when only one device is connected.

However when multiple android devices are connected, the shell script does not work because I can not specify the android device id.

The question is **how I can get the android device id in build.gralde file using Android Studio?**

**build.gradle**

```
task clearHome(type: Exec) {

    Properties properties = new Properties()
    properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
    def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')

    // I'd like to know <android device id> that I selected using Android Stdio.
    commandLine file('../beforeInstall.sh').absolutePath, sdkDir <android device id>
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn clearHome
}
```

**beforeInstall.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

ADB=$1/platform-tools/adb
ADB_SHELL="$ADB -s $2 shell"

$ADB_SHELL pm enable com.android.launcher
$ADB_SHELL am start -n com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher
```

Comment: have you tried `adb shell sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db "SELECT value FROM secure WHERE name='android_id'"
`

Comment: The connected devices are not the same always.

Comment: did you reset your devices?

Comment: You may misunderstand. Android devices are not problem. I want to know which device I choose at the target select dialog of Android studio.

Comment: Did you ever come up with a decent solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understood the problem, but if you're running the gradle script by command line, you can always pass a property to it..
ie:

```
gradle somegradletask -P**propertyDeviceId=123456789**
```

You just need to get the Id from the adb shell first, pass it on to the gradle script.
Then, inside the gradle script use the **propertyDeviceId**

```
androidDeviceId = propertyDevicecId;
commandLine file('../beforeInstall.sh').absolutePath, sdkDir <androidDeviceId>
```

Happy Coding (or hacking) ;)

Comment: Um, the deviceID is always different.  I want to know which device I choose at the target select dialog of Android studio.